# Using separate model for each column in table ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I like to create a table. for each column in this table I like to use a different model. So if I drop a element in one of my two columns it should store the element in the model with respect to the column. [Here is link](https://jsfiddle.net/7ta8Lngs/6/) to a fiddle page where I tried something. Is that the easiest way to do so?

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in data">
      <div data-drag="true" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid', helper: 'clone'}" jqyoui-draggable="{animate: true, placeholder: 'keep'}" ng-model="person">
        {{ person.name }}
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>



  <table >
    <tr style="background-color:orange;">
      <td ng-model="src" data-drop="true" jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true, onDrop: 'myDrop'}">Add your items here</td>
      <td ng-model="tar" data-drop="true" jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true, onDrop: 'myDrop'}">Add your items here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in src track by $index">
      <td >{{ person.name }}</td>
      <td >{{ tar[$index].name }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngDragDrop']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  var src = [{
    name: 'bob'
  }, {
    name: 'mary'
  }];
  var tar = [{
    name: 'bob'
  }, {
    name: 'mary'
  }];
  $scope.people = [];
  $scope.people.src = [];
  $scope.people.tar = [];
  $scope.data = src;
  $scope.hideMe = function() {
    return $scope.people.src > 0;
  }
  $scope.myDrop = function(event, ui) {
    console.log($scope.people);
  }

});
</script>
```

Comment: `td` elements don't use `ngModel` - nor do `div` elementas

Comment: @tymeJV Are you sure, the code above is working somehow, you can also check the fiddle.

Comment: Nvm, I didn't see the drag and drop plugin - I assume the ngModel is for the plugin now.